# Подскажите какие задачи выполняет функция

Tags: php

Имеется функция, подскажите какие точно задачи она выполняет и помогите расшифровать приблизительные названия переменных. Спасибо.

```
function _obfuscate_BjRgIGV9eHgPJSgBEHtteQяя($_obfuscate_kIVhqJkя, $_obfuscate_FeCnJIvj, $cnt)
{
    $_obfuscate_f517kgяя = array_keys( $_obfuscate_kIVhqJkя );
    if ($_obfuscate_FeCnJIvj == -1)
    {
        $_obfuscate_FeCnJIvj = 0;
        shuffle($_obfuscate_f517kgяя);
    }
    $_obfuscate_f517kgяя = array_slice($_obfuscate_f517kgяя, $_obfuscate_FeCnJIvj, $cnt);
    foreach($_obfuscate_f517kgяя as $_obfuscate_Vwty)
    {
        $my[$_obfuscate_Vwty] = $_obfuscate_kIVhqJkя[$_obfuscate_Vwty];
    }
    return $my;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function my_function($array, $offset, $cnt)
{
    $array_keys = array_keys( $array );
    if ($offset == -1)
    {
        $offset = 0;
        shuffle($array_keys);
    }
    $array_keys = array_slice($array_keys, $offset, $cnt);
    foreach($array_keys as $key)
    {
        $my[$key] = $array[$key];
    }
    return $my;
}
```

Так понятнее?

Comment: наверно, стоит словами сказать в чём возможная цель функции (и более специфичное имя дать, вместо `my_function()`), и как именно это реализовано (2-3 шага).

Comment: Есть массив array(1,2,3,4,5), нужно вытащить первые два элемента, воспользуемся функцией my_function(array(1,2,3,4,5),0,2) - получим array(1,2). $array - массив, $offset - с какого элемента начинаем, $cnt - сколько элементов нужно вырезать. Проще некуда.